# FullCalendar adjacent events stacking oddly with events which have multiline titles

Tags: fullcalendar

I am transitioning a webpage that is using fullcalendar 1.x, to fullcalendar 2.x. It seems with the new layout style the calendar is mainly built for events which are a single line, or at the very least similar heights. To get around the single line title issue the popular resolution seems to be: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1992 , specifically the

```
.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

css rule.

However, there seems to be a problem with white space stacking on adjacent events. An example screenshot can be seen here:

A jsbin with a similar issue can be found here: http://jsbin.com/vegopabegu/2/edit . The whitespace I would like to remove is highlighted in this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/k7wvF9JPOtM . I have yet to figure out a good way to post process these events to stack them a bit more efficiently and avoid whitespace generated by differing  heights.

Has anyone overcome this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do this without rebuilding entire structure of the calendar. The whitespace you indicated is there because of table rows that expands themselves to fit the content of the longest cell in the row.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to accomplish in pure CSS without changing the code of FullCalendar. Even if you decide to change the FullCalendar code, then still this is hard to accomplish. This is caused by the fact that a table is used for rendering the calendar. The whitespace you want removed is caused due to that all these events are populated on one table row. Getting FullCalendar to properly use a table and stack the events using div's is hard to accomplish. I couldn't find anyone who tried this and succeeded in doing this.

The only simple solution I can think of for now is to give the events the same height so the white space doesn't show:

```
a.fc-event{
  height: 34px;
}
```

See here: http://jsbin.com/cudovagasu/1

Another solution is removing the blue backgrounds so the whitespace becomes invisible:

```
a.fc-event{
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: black;
}
a.fc-event:hover{
  color: #3a87ad;
}
```

See here: http://jsbin.com/cudovagasu/2

Another possible solution is to drop FullCalendar and try to find another calendar library which doesn't have this issue.